# Given a set of points, find the one that has the smallest Manhattan distance from a query point

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl, tree

I am trying to solve a competitive programming question that asks me to find the closest point to another. The metric used is Manhattan distance.

**What I have tried so far**

*Inefficient and complicated solution*

This is what I have managed so far. Manhattan distance between two points is:

```
|x1 - x2| + |y1 - y2|
```

Given a distance *r*, the points that lie at most *r* distance away from the point satisfy the inequality

```
|x1 - x2| + |y1 - y2| <= r
```

This forms a diamond like shape in the plane (a square rotated by 45 degrees)

So what I did was, I rotated the points by 45 degrees, so the figure turned into a square. I could now check if two points were at most *r* units away, if their x and y coordinates were at most *r* units apart.

```
max(|x1 - x2|, |y1 - y2|) <= r
```

To efficiently check if any point in the DB lies at most *r* units away from a given point, I used a segment tree to find y-values of all points that lie between *x - r* and *x + r* and checked if at least one y-value was in the range *y - r* and *y + r*

Since my task was to find the lowest Manhattan distance, I applied binary search on the possible values of *r*.

My solution solves each query in O(log<sup>3</sup> n) time. One log n comes from binary search, one to check the segment tree, and one to verify if the y-values fall in range.
This is too much for the problem constraints. I need at most O(log<sup>2</sup> n) query processing time.

Could someone recommend a data structure that will perform better?

Comment: Have a look into R-trees (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). They divide space up into boxes which can then be searched over to find the Nth nearest point to the query point (in your case N would be 1).

Comment: How does the input look like ? Do you have to build your structure during the timing ?

Comment: @Jarod42 10^5 points. 50k queries. 5 seconds limit in a competitive programming environment. They did not specify number of test cases.

Comment: @DXsmiley I didn't use R-Trees for my solution but they would've probably worked. Do you have any good resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a k-d-tree

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Comment: This worked like a charm! May not be the best solution out there, but it certainly was efficient enough for the question.